# Ocultar radioButton con CSS

Tags: css, html5

Tengo un problema en un estilo css ya que tengo un codigo de unos inputs radioButtons en forma de boton
que al darle clic se selecciona el radioButton pero no eh podido ocultar los radioButton para que solo muestre los label como si fuera un boton este es mi codigo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CSS

.panel {
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    }

```
#donate label {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    #donate label span {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 3px 0px;
        display: block;
    }

    #donate label input {
        position: absolute;            
        /*top: -20px;*/
    }

#donate input:checked + span {
    background-color: #404040;
    color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

HTML

```
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Estilo de fuente:</label>
                <div id="donate" style="z-index: 100">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span><strong>N</strong></span></label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>I</span></label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span><u>S</u></span></label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ocultar tu radiobutton usa la propiedad [`opacity`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp) para  darle un valor de transparencia entre 0 y 1 siendo 1 no transparente y 0 totalmente transparente.

Agregue un ejemplo de Jquery para que vieras que si se captura la selección de un radiobutton.

```js
$("input").change(function() {
  alert("se seleciono un radiobutton");
});
```

```css
.panel {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

#donate label {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#donate label span {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 3px 0px;
  display: block;
}

#donate label input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  /*top: -20px;*/
}

#donate input:checked+span {
  background-color: #404040;
  color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
  <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Estilo de fuente:</label>
  <div id="donate" style="z-index: 100">
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span><strong>N</strong></span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>I</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span><u>S</u></span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: y el valor que se selecciono en radioButton si se puede recuperar de forma normal con JQuery, o ya no se puede recuperar ese valor que se ha seleccionado en el radioButton

Comment: @Ivxn solo  se cambio la opacidad si haces click si se recupera cosa que no pasaría con un `display: none;` que  oculta el elemento.

Comment: @bercklynCarlosviza eso es correcto a medias, con jquery uno puede obtener el valor como lo muestro en la edición de mi respuesta y cualquier browser moderno (hace años) también envía un input con display:none. No son enviados inputs con propiedad "disabled", es solo una aclaracion para no confundir a nadie que lea ese comentario, mas allá de esta aclaración tu respuesta es valida opacity:0 también cumple con el propósito de la pregunta.

Comment: @LeonardoCabré Tienes razón  en parte porque al tener esa estructura el input puede tranquilamente usarse `display:none`  pero sino la tuviera   no funcionaria ya que quien recibe la función click es el label y no el input  porque este esta oculto.

Answer (score 3):

puedes agregar esto:

```
#donate label input {
    position: absolute;            
    display:none; /* <- agregado */
}
```

Tambien te cambie el `#donate label span` para que ocupe bien todo el contenido del label.

```
#donate label span {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 0px; /* <- modificado */
    display: block;
}
```

```js
$("input").change(function() {
  console.log($(this).val())
});
```

```css
#donate label {
    float: left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#donate label span {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    display: block;
}

#donate label input {
    position: absolute;            
    display:none;
}

#donate input:checked + span {
    background-color: #404040;
    color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03">Estilo de fuente:</label>
    <div id="donate" style="z-index: 100">
        <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" value="1"><span><strong>N</strong></span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" value="2"><span>I</span></label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="toggle" value="3"><span><u>S</u></span></label>
    </div>
</div>
```